# Drivers only working for Z rotation on some objects within scene

Tags: drivers

I'm having a problem rendering a scene with multiple icospheres animated using drivers. I'm using X and Y drivers to move the objects along an ellipse (closed) path. And I'm using Euler Z rotation to rotate those objects on their Z-axis while they orbit. (fundamentally mimicking solar system orbits for the main planets).  The problem I'm seeing is that only Z rotations are working for some objects but not X Y translations.

When I'm in 3d view and hit the play button in the timeline, orbital rotation (around the object at 0,0,0) works fine for each of the 8 icospheres, so they move properly around an elliptical path (bezier curve object) about the sun (icosphere at 0,0,0). The reason the bezier curve exists is that initially I was using a simple path animation, but opted to use drivers to better control the "planet" motions more to scale with reality.

The Z rotations mimicking sidereal day periods also work fine in the 3d view. When I try to render this blend however, there is only the motion on the Z rotations, and all of the XY translations fail to render, so the planets simply spin in their original position.

X location driver code (not working in render)

```py
0 + (sin(radians(frame/rotation_period)) * (major_axis/2))
```

Y location driver code (not working in render)

```py
0 + (cos(radians(frame/rotation_period)) * (minor_axis/2))
```

for completeness, these are the working Z rotation driver settings

```py
0 if frame == 0 else radians(degrees(2*pi)/((local_rotation_period/1)/23.5))*frame
```

Notes:

- No errors are logged on any of the drivers in any interface.
- the custom  "rotation_period" exists for all objects independently.
- it's properly added to the driver interface as a single value.
- Initially, I used simple path animations, that's why the bezier curve orbit guides exist (disabled in render), but fundamentally, having them there allows me to know the X and Y drivers are working as expected (in 3d view)
- when enabling the driver, I disabled the path animation by disabling the constraint and unchecking the animate path checkbox in the object settings, I cleared the location on the target object (putting it back to 0,0,0 origin, then made the origin the object geometry, there seemed to be an issue properly following the curve ellipses if the object had world origin) , and then attached the X and Y driver setup.

  - I did some review/checkup and i don't see that I have any of the drivers disabled from contributing to the render output & I don't have any translation channels locked
  - I also have a set of 4 armatures controlling curve guide fields with a driver manipulating their x/y translation and they work fine in 3d view & rendered. Which makes me suspicious that maybe some way that i'm using the driver specifically for the planet orbit translations is buggy? The driver code which does translations and does work in render view is below:

```py
sin(frame/50)*100
```

I can really use some help working this out, I've been working on the blend for quite some time and it's become a thing lol. I do prefer the driver based motion to the path animations which were very choppy and harder to tweak given the requirements. I can add any additional details needed, thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggest using `360` in place of `degrees(2 * pi)` above

Comment: thanks, I will give it a shot. that was a WIP honestly, it started as the standard formula for angular displacement and kind of morphed into something else lol.